# @PostConstruct method is not getting called in junit

Tags: java, junit5

I am using junit 5.7.2 , I am using a factory design pattern where in I populate a map inside the postConstruct method. I need to write junit for that but postconstruct method is not getting invoked.

Comment: I take it that the class under test is not created by the bean container? If so: We have to invoke it manually. It is the bean containers responsibility to call the `@PostConstruct` method at runtime [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the instance was created by the bean container.

Comment: In unit-testing we test only 1 class, so we don't test all Spring context. For testing your class, you should invoke method with @PostConstruct annotation in your test